# Can't get Firefox to load Please help!

Tags: firefox

Got a problem with FireFox, I installed Enlightenment (e17) and I added a .png to the Icon on the desktop to change the way the icon looks.  Now my problem is I uninstalled e17 and now I'm just using Ubuntu Desktop but Ubuntu keeps looking for that old path to the icon I super imposed onto FireFox in e17, I tried uninstalling FireFox and reinstalled it, but FireFox will not boot the only way it boots is when I'm in Terminal and type FireFox.

I don't understand how I can get FireFox to work again?  FYI I removed FFox in Ubuntu Software Centre and also through Synaptic and reinstalled through both, but it's still looking for that path to the icon which does not exist.

Please help.  :)  PS I know I screwed it up trying to make the shortcut icon to firefox to look different, but is there a way to make ubuntu forget the icon path?

Comment: How did you apply or associate the image with Firefox?

Comment: I can't quite remember I know it had something to do with changing the icon image and now it's always looking for that image.  Stupid me.  messing with things I should be messin with.  But I'll just do a reinstall and back up my hard drive usually only takes me an hour or so to set up Ubuntu the way I like it.  This is why I love Linux no subscription, no serial codes, and no malware, adware or viruses.  I love UBUNTU!